# Find Minium of Function with Integral Values...

Tags: functions, optimization

I need to find the minimum of the following function for $J(n)$ where $n$ is an integer.

$$J(n) = \theta +\frac{\lambda  (\theta  \mu  n (\theta  \mu  n+2)+2)}{2 \mu ^2 n \left(1-\lambda  n \left(\theta +\frac{1}{\mu  n}\right)\right)}+\frac{1}{\mu  n}$$

I know that if $n$ can be real, then we simply take the derivative, set it to 0, and solve for $n$ and we get the following:

$$n=\frac{2 \theta  \lambda  \mu -\sqrt{2} \sqrt{\theta ^2 \lambda ^3 \mu +\theta ^2 \lambda  \mu ^3}}{\theta ^2 \lambda ^2 \mu -\theta ^2 \lambda  \mu ^2}$$

Or

$$n=\frac{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{\theta ^2 \lambda ^3 \mu +\theta ^2 \lambda  \mu ^3}+2 \theta  \lambda  \mu }{\theta ^2 \lambda ^2 \mu -\theta ^2 \lambda  \mu ^2}$$

But the problem is I want a method to find the minimum assuming that $n$ are integers...How is this possible? What methods are available to do this?

Comment: If the derivative when $n$ is real is well-behaved, then you can look at the integers around the real minimum.

Comment: That's what I thought, but when I asked someone much more knowledgeable than I, they said I was WRONG. Could this be solved using Integer programming or something as well - NOTE: I agree with your point, however

Comment: The statement that I made is not true in general, but is true in special cases.  For example, if a univariate function has a unique local minimum, then you can just look around the real minimum, but if the function is more complicated, then this won't work.  As for integer programming, this really doesn't look like a good application of integer programming because the functions aren't linear.

Comment: what is the range of the given variables?

Comment: All variables are > 0